# How to set Default Local Storage Location in Sonatype Nexus

Tags: nexus, sonatype

I want  to set the  Default Local Storage Location in Sonatype Nexus, can someone please tell me how to do that from back end ?

Do we set the value in nexus.xml or somewhere else ?

Answer (score 1):

> These are defined they will override the values in
> "$NEXUS_HOME/conf/nexus.properties". For Nexus 2.x the following
> environment variables can be defined
>
> **NEXUS_WORK**
>
> The location of the nexus work directory, where nexus stores all of
> its configurations and repository contents. Defaults to
> $(basedir)/../sonatype-work/nexus

Please refer to this: [How to set Sonatype Nexus Storage](https://support.sonatype.com/entries/30145206-Can-I-override-Nexus-configuration-properties-with-environment-variables-)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Added essential part to the answer

Comment: Looks Good. Thanks. :)